# Asterisk Call Transfer to Analog Phone

Tags: centos, asterisk, pabx

We have an IVR setup that we've been working on lately. We have dial plan that is working fine, we have 1 PRI line connected to our Server (FXM8aPCI card) coming from PABX, also there are 4 analog phones connected with PABX to transfer the calls to sales/support service, we don't have SIP! Only analog phone.

Right now when we use Dial() method to transfer the calls to analog phone, like this:

```
Dial(DAHDI/1/106)
```

it would return an error called "Cause 17 - user busy", channel 1 is the channel on which user currently is on and listening to IVR menu, how do we just transfer the line? when we use `Transfer(DAHDI/1/106)` it doesn't work.

To check this error, we plugged in another line in another channel #2, coming from pabx aswell, now when we did this:

`Dial(DAHDI/3/106)` it works, but then again it takes up the channel, as if another user calls and press 0 to go to extension 106, it says Cause 17 user busy.

One last issue is when the call is picked up from extension #106 we only listen a loud noise like "someone is blowing an air in the receiver!".

Answer (score 0):

Analog phone connected via 1 wire can accept only ONE call.

You can use call waiting/hold or parking if you want. But anyway you can't use more then 1 line per phone.

Comment: Ok but is the approach right? plugging an extra line from pbx to the server just to dial an extension? also how can i do call waiting/hold or parking?

Comment: Callwaiting can be enaled in dahdi.conf if your line is analog. But i highly recommend you use sip adapter like SPA2002, it much simpler to manage and control. For code used for parking/transfer see features.conf